# Center only heading text in a table

Tags: tables

I need your help.
I want to get a heading text center aligned, but the rest of the table, left aligned only.
I tried with some advice in other post: `\multicolumn {number of columns}{type of align}{heading}` but I don't get it.
I want the same result of my solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{\textbf{DOC TITLE}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{2.5cm}{2.5cm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\footnotesize{TEXT}}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{23}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{60}|}
\hline\rowcolor{Gray}
\textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\\ [1ex]
\hline
\begin{flushleft} Text \end{flushleft}\\
\hline
\begin{flushleft} Text \end{flushleft}\\
\hline
text & text
\hline
text & text
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want a table like this, it has errors:[image: Table]

Please help me!

Comment: It is not clear what is your "solution". The code you provided does not compile (missing units in the `m` specification, missing \\ before some `\hline`s ...) You didn't provided a MWE, since the preamble is important (apparently packages `color` and `colortbl` are required). If your problem is that you don't know how to make your example compile, then you should at least provide a mockup of the desired result.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but don't just use `[h]` as that makes it very likely that this table and all following ones to go to the end of the document. always include at least `p` something like `[htp]` or not using the option at all would be better.

Comment: @JLDiaz Thanks for your comment, I edited it.

Comment: @Isai Still does not compile. And I didn't get yet what is the output you want. Could you provide an image (even a mockup)?

Comment: @ JLDiaZ I re-edited it. I hope that it is the complete code, because I'm using a phone to do it, and I can't attach an image.

Comment: @JLDiaz I wrote all preamble that I have, and I upload an image with that I want. Could you please review it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's easier to define the general alignment of the table, and use multicolum to center the header text:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{23mm}|m{23mm}|m{60mm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{23mm}|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Very long title}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{23mm}|}{\textbf{Very long title}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{60mm}|}{\textbf{Normal title}}\\
\hline
Text & Text 
    & Very very very very very very very very very very 
        very veryvery very very very very very very very long text \\
\hline
Very very very very very verryy very very very very very long text 
    & Very very very very very verryy very very very very very long text
    & Text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I have modified my answer to reflect your example.

- Column 1 is left aligned, as asked, using `\raggedright`
- Column 2 is justified (normal paragraphs) with the same content as the column 1
- Column 3 is justified with a short title

[image: Table]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but, How can I define the columns width? Because there's an error with:     |l{23mm}|

Comment: @Isai I've changed the definition of the tabular to fit your needs

Comment: I'm sorry, but the table fits for the heading text, no matter the column width definition. And I've lost the color of the cells heading.

Comment: @Isai For the color, just put the `\rowcolor` inside the `\multicolumn`. For the column width, I do not understand: they are defined to have 23 mm and 60 mm (you should not forget the unit, as pointed above by JLDiaz).

Comment: What happen if I would like to write a long text for heading, for me it doesn't work, because the column width is bigger than I defined, as long as the text in a single line.

Comment: For a long text, you need to choose an appropriate definition, like `|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{23mm}|` instead of `|c|` in the `\multicolumn`

Comment: With TeX Live 2018, the `\rowcolor{Gray}` must come before the `\multicolumn{1}`, then everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 26):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htb]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| m{23pt} | m{60pt}|}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{black!30}\textbf{text}} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{black!30}\textbf{text}}\\\hline
Text & Text\\\hline
Text & T \\\hline
text & text\\\hline
text & t\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or for long headings:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htb]
\caption{Title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| m{23pt} | m{60pt}|}\hline
\rowcolor{black!30}\Centering\bfseries foo
  & \Centering\bfseries Her comes some extremely long text for the first heading\\\hline
Text & Text\\\hline
Text & T \\\hline
text & text\\\hline
text & t\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the baselines in the lengthy text are really too widely spaced.  if a `parbox` were used with centered text, they'd look more like continuous text.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work with my table. Maybe I'm wrong: `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Text}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|m{23mm}|m{45mm}|m{45mm}|m{45mm}|m{45mm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!30}
\centering\bfseries Text & \centering\bfseries Text & \centering\bfseries Text & \centering\bfseries Text & \centering\bfseries Text\\[0.5ex]
\hline
Text & Text & Text & Text & Text\\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}`

Comment: @Isai: I used `\Centering` with an uppercase C, which is important here!

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{caption} \label{tbl}
\begin{tabular}{|L{6cm}|L{8cm}|}
    \hline
    \thead{head 1} & \thead{head2} \\
    \hline
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This works quite well, thanks! Is it just me, or is the vertical line separating the two columns actually thicker in the header row than it is in the other rows?