# Multiple alignments within tables

Tags: tables, alignment

How can I create tables with multiple alignments as shown? The first row (i.e. the headings) is centre aligned and the subsequent rows are left aligned?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Compressible} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Incompressible}  \\  \hline

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb \\
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Mico My knowledge about formatting tables is limited. But some users stack  the tabular function (as in use the tabular within a tabular) to get different alignments under a column. Will that work? It seems too much to do though.

Comment: Just use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` for the cells to be centered, see here for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87596/center-only-heading-text-in-a-table

Comment: This site: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/# could also be useful.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I'm confused with how multicolumn works, is there anything I could read to understand it more clearly?

Comment: @JoshuaMathewJacob Look at here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Rows_spanning_multiple_columns

Comment: @CarLaTeX thanks I've got it. I'm now able to centre my headings. But now my table seems to overrun the page. How can I fix that?

Comment: @JoshuaMathewJacob Try to create a minimal example of your code which reproduces your problem and add it to your question. Perhaps you used `l` for column specification, not `p{...}`, but it's impossible to help you without an MWE. https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=606

Comment: @CarLaTeX I've added it to the body of the post

Comment: Off-topic: `8pt` is not a recognized option for the `book` document class, and will thus get ignored. The `book` class recognizes only three options regarding the main document font size: `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. You'll need a different class, or load a package that does its own font size calculations, if `8pt` is supposed to be the main font size for the entire document.

Comment: @CarLaTeX thank you very much! btw can you also tell me how to make numbered lists inside the cells of a table? Edit on this sample of code itself if possible....

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the info. I’ve a lot to learn. A doubt tho: if its ignored will the default be 12pt?

Comment: @JoshuaMathewJacob - No, the default is `10pt`.

Comment: @Mico thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `tabularx`.

Please note that `multicol` package is for having a document in two (or more) columns, it is not for `\multicolumn` in tables.

Please also observe that because I've set the width of the `tabularx` environment to equal `\linewidth`, the `\centering` instruction is no longer needed.

As egreg pointed out in his comment, if the table has no caption, a `center` environment suffices; if it has a caption, then `table` should not have the `[H]` option.

For more professional tables, use `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
If your table is at a fixed position, you can use 
\texttt{center} environment.
%\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
%%\centering %% not needed since width of tabularx env. = \linewidth
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\RaggedRight}X|}
 \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{Compressible} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Incompressible}  \\  \hline
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb \\
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd  \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
%\end{table}
\end{center}

If your table has a caption, the \texttt{[H]} option should not be used, because it can float.
Table \ref{tab:mytab} is an example
with \texttt{booktabs}.
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{\label{tab:mytab}A professional table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\RaggedRight}X}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Compressible} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Incompressible} \\  
\midrule
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbb \\
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Please remove the meaningless `8pt` document class option from the code block, though.

Comment: Perhaps you should add `>{\RaggedRight}` in front of X, in the table preamble.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: If the table has no caption, a `center` environment suffices; if it has a caption, then `table` should not have the `[H]` option.

Comment: @egreg Added, thanks!