Reduce vertical space in longtable cells
I have an .xsl file that is parsing Word tables and generating LaTex tables. I have to use the longtable package as the tables can be quite long. The results aren't too bad, but I don't know how to tighten up the vertical space in the table cells. Here is my sample code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{longtable}{| p{.73cm} | p{1.74cm} | p{2.82cm} | p{2.18cm} | p{.86cm} | p{.86cm} | p{2.28cm} |}
\hline
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 1}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 2}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 3}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 4}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 5}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 6}}}}
\end{center}
 & 
\begin{center}
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{\textbf{{\scriptsize Col 7}}}}
\end{center}
\endhead \hline

{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{\scriptsize Cell 1}}}
 & 
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{\scriptsize Not Connected}}}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 \\ \hline
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{\scriptsize Cell 2}}}
 & 
{\sffamily \textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{\scriptsize Not Connected}}}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 & 
\begin{flushright}

\end{flushright}
 \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{document}

How can I tighten the space in the cells?
Thanks for any help!
Russ

Get rid of all flush and center environments. Those add vertical space.

Is there another way to center the header elements without using \begin{center} and \end{center} commands?

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{content} for example.... With a bit of care for the vertical lines (or get rid of them...). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87596/center-only-heading-text-in-a-table

You can also use tabularray for a more compact design

@Mane32 I had been using tabularray, and wanted to continue to use it,  but the tables were too big for it to handle

I suggest you get rid of the center and flushright environments and set up the column specifications appropriately.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

% New:
\usepackage{array}    % for "\newcolumntype" maccro
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\RaggedLeft" macro
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}} % do you maybe want "\RaggedRight"?
% Define two handy shortcut macros
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries #1}}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next few directives
\sffamily
\scriptsize % 30% linear reduction in font size
% \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % optional (default value: 6pt)
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"

\begin{longtable}{| R{.73cm} | R{1.74cm} | R{2.82cm} | R{2.18cm} 
   | R{.86cm} | R{.86cm} | R{2.28cm} |}

%% header row

\hline
\mcx{Col 1} & \mc{Col 2} & \mc{Col 3} & \mc{Col 4} 
   & \mc{Col 5} & \mc{Col 6} & \mc{Col 7} \\
\hline
\endhead

%% body of table

Cell 1 & Not Connected & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\ 
\hline 
Cell 2 & Not Connected & & & & & \\ 
\hline

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}


That's very nice, thank you!
